# Netflix logout does not revoke secure netflix ids

Tags: authentication, oauth2

I am learning about microservice security and I wanted to see if Netflix really logs me out.
While logged into Netflix, I opened `https://www.netflix.com/YourAccount` and in inspector viewed headers I am sending.

After copying the headers, I logged out -> opened Postman and issued the same request with the copied headers. The result - I could see my account information so the tokens were not revoked.

Is it a standard to keep auth tokens *hanging*?

Doesn't it make user of the site more prone to attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One benefit of signed auth tokens is the ability to implement them stateless. This means that the server doesn't have to keep track of active tokens, but verifies the validity of a token by checking its signature and the claims contained in the token. Those claims usually contain a short lived expiration date, something like 5 minutes.

A simple logout routine might just delete the token on client side, which results exactly in the behavior you have witnessed. A copy of this token is still valid, until the lifetime has ended.

So you are right - this leaves you vulnerable for a short amount of time, if someone was able to steal your auth token.

The application can actually implement a clean logout, by remembering the active token in a "logged-out list" on server side, until the lifetime of the token has ended. If someone tries to use the token, the server would find its id in the "logged-out list" and denies access. Based on your observation, Netflix decided against this mechanism.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe there are reasons why would one not make revoked token list? I don'tsee any apart from making system more stateless and not needing to have distributed revokation list.

Comment: Some systems do. Security is always a trade-off. In this case the user is barely more vulnerable for that short amount of time afterwards (and the token isn't even present anywhere asides from previously captured network traffic). In most cases that's a better trade-off. There are two big things that should be considered with the revocation list: 1. There's maintenance for when those tokens should be deleted from the db. 2. There's a performance impact to check the revocation list each request.

Comment: Maintaining a logged-out list makes the tokens stateful and negates a large reason for their existence. If you were going to maintain a logged-out-list it would probably be easier to just use regular, stateful, sessions

Comment: @ConorMancone - It is a trade-off, sure. But the list of logged out token-ids is just a fraction of actual amount of tokens out there, so it may be a good compromise. It of course depends on the surrounding factors and must be evaluated individually.